# Controller only returning 1 view rather than choosing the correct view

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-2.0

I have 2 controllers which both display the same view, the first shows a specific SSO provider and the other shows all SSO providers. When posting the login form and something goes wrong, the [HttpPost] controller either returns /account/login or /account/login?code=Facebook but both are the 2nd view. Is it possible to return the /account/{code}/login view if the code is not null and return the other view if it is? With either view returned I need the model and any errors to be kept when the view is returned.

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("/account/{code}/login")]
[AllowAnonymous]
public async Task<IActionResult> Login(string code, string returnUrl = null)
{

    ViewData["ReturnUrl"] = returnUrl;
    ViewData["Code"] = code;
    LoginViewModel model = new LoginViewModel();
    model.SocialLogins = new List<string> { code };
    return View(model);
}
[HttpGet]
[Route("/account/login")]
[AllowAnonymous]
public async Task<IActionResult> Login(string returnUrl = null)
{
    ViewData["ReturnUrl"] = returnUrl;
    LoginViewModel model = new LoginViewModel();
    model.SocialLogins = _socialLogins;
    return View(model);
}

[HttpPost]
[AllowAnonymous]
[Route("/account/login")]
[Route("/account/{code}/login")]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<IActionResult> Login(LoginViewModel model, string code = null, string returnUrl = null)
{
    ViewData["Code"] = code;
    ViewData["ReturnUrl"] = returnUrl;
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        //login code
    }

    return View(model);
}

public class LoginViewModel
{
    [Required]
    [EmailAddress]
    public string Email { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    public string Password { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Remember me?")]
    public bool RememberMe { get; set; }

    public List<string> SocialLogins { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: You can explicitly define the view name in your return View statement. Syntax is return View(""ViewName",model); Hope this helps. Pls let me know if this what you looking for.

Comment: @NishantShrivastava has a right, but be awere, that `POST /account/Facebook/login` will handled by controller the same way as `POST /account/login?code=Facebook`

Comment: @NishantShrivastava This does not work as both Login views have the same name and when you use return View(nameof(Login), model); it still just returns to the /account/login view not the /account/code/login view

Comment: What is the cshtml file name of `/account/code/login` view?

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya Both Controller return Login.cshtml